# JAVA/MSSQL: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, groovy

I have got a problem with database queries, when I try to run them from my groovy script. Sometimes, but very often, I've got an error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:2156)
```

The module which I used for connection to database is:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
def dbUser = "username"
def dbPassword = 'password'
def dbDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
def dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-server"
def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
```

The script started by windows scheduler on Windows Server 2012 every 2 minutes. And I use developer machine where I'm making code and running the script from this size also. There was no problem problem, when I used MySQL database, but after migrating database on MSSQL, I see this error.

Comment: Please show the full script, especially the query execution.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel query is simple: `full_debug_query= "INSERT INTO log.dbo.debug (date, number1, number2, action, details, query) VALUES (GETDATE(),'"+number1+"','"+number2+"', '"+action+"', '"+comment+"', '"+query+"')"; try{sql.execute(full_debug_query);}catch(e){ex=e}`

Answer (score 0):

That can be caused by several reasons:

1. A bug in your script. The connection is closed somewhere (maybe because of an exception which you don't handle properly) and then you try to use it again. Check exception and resource handling.
2. You're keeping a connection open for too long. After a certain timeout, the database closes the connection on their side.
3. Someone restarted the database server.

It's most likely not a firewall issue; firewalls just drop packets when the connection times out, so the application appears to "hang" instead of giving a good error message.

Comment: 1. jdbc driver close connections automatically after query. Also I close connection at end of script. `sql.close()`.

Comment: 2. there is no any apparent timeout errors during running script. I know how is look this error. It's like when your start the script, It's take a pause during running and then you have got an error like `The connection is closed.` because timeout. This is not my example. I've got this error at once.

Comment: 3. Server working fine. And there is no problems with database.

Comment: Is it possible that problem is that script runs from two workstations at the same time? Sometimes I've got an error: `PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL

INFO: java.security path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\security
Security providers: [SUN version 1.8, SunRsaSign v,... bla-bla-bla`

Comment: Can you post a _minimal_ example script that shows the behaviour?

Comment: @tim_yates minimal example is above. After as I get `sql` connection, I run query `sql.execute("INSERT INTO log.dbo.debug (date, number1, number2, action, details, query) VALUES (GETDATE(),'12345678','1234567891', 'test', 'test', 'test') ")`

Comment: Do you have configured connection pooling somewhere? Is the MS SQL server running out of connections?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla `select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
where counter_name ='User Connections'` show me that `cntr_value 59` and `cntr_type 65792`.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla `select * from sys.configurations
where name ='user connections'` show me that `value 0`,`minimum 0`,`maximum 32767`,`value in use 0`

Comment: @Aaron Digulla @tim_yates I stopped script on main server and run it manually. First run going with error `The connection is closed`, second is fine. Then I run it again and result is similar: first run going with error and second is ok.. Look like script not close connection.. but I have `sql.close()` in it

Comment: Please add logging around the `sql.close()` call so you can see whether it's actually executed.